# Parameters added twice on redirect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that is redirecting users to a specific google.XX and that is adding parameters at the end of the url.

The extension is working pretty well, except that my parameters are added two times. It is still working but I want the code to be as clean as possible.

Here is the script :

background.js

```
var HOST = null;
var parameters = null;
var icon = null;

function handler(details) {
  if (HOST != null) {
    return {redirectUrl: HOST + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1] + parameters};
  } else {
    return {}; // do nothing
  }
}

// Do this at the top level
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(handler,{
        urls: [
            "*://www.google.com/search*",
            "*://www.google.ie/search*",
            "*://www.google.it/search*",
            "*://www.google.es/search*",
            "*://www.google.fr/search*",
            "*://www.google.nl/search*",
            "*://www.google.be/search*",
            "*://www.google.co.uk/search*",
            "*://www.google.de/search*",
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]);
```

So at the end, I'll end up in my url bar with : newHost/****+param+param

I guess the redirection is causing that. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check to see if the parameter exists before appending it. Something like this should work.

```
function handler(details) {
  var url = details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1];
  if (HOST != null && url.indexOf(parameters) === -1) {
    return {redirectUrl: HOST + url + parameters};
  } else {
    return {}; // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that you meant `url = url + parameters`. In addition, I suggest to move `redirectUrl` inside the `if` as well. The code currently works because of sheer luck: somehow onBeforeRedirect does not recurse (this behavior is undocumented so it could change at any time in the future).